# JSON matchers for ScalaTest

Tags: json, scalatest

Are there any JSON matchers for ScalaTest?

Sorry for being ignorant, I don't believe that they do not exist and I the first person who needs them ;(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would think that JSON matchers for ScalaTest would have to depend on a Scala JSON library, and there are several different libraries out there.